# When querying a sharded collection, can I filter on shard keys using an operator?

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, sharding

I need to update many documents in a Mongo collection sharded on the `_id` field. I already have the IDs available in a list. Can I update the documents using something like `.update_many({"_id": {"$in": ids_to_update}}, ...`, or should I instead use `bulkWrite` to create an `updateOne` operation for every ID?

Comment: Come to think of it, using an `$in` operator probably requires more computational overhead than just pinpointing each doc to update using `bulkWrite`, right?

Comment: I don't think it makes any difference. Do you need to update all documents with the same value?

Comment: Do you really shard on `_id`? Or do you use the hash-key sharding?

Comment: Yes we are sharding on `_id` at the moment. Worth mentioning we generate this field ourselves. And yes in this case the upsert operation is identical across documents.